# Is it possible to save a model without uploading a file?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that contains a [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#filefield). I am manually saving the file through an API call, though, so I don't want the model to upload anything for the `FileField`, but I do want it to save the file name and location. Can this be done?

Comment: You can set the name the file to FileField without the file: `model.file_field = "path/name.png"` and save the model.

Comment: Will it not automatically try to save the actual file?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I just did, you're right. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: Don'r delete. This will be useful to anybody in future searching for the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do not use a model form to save the data, no file is added to the filesystem. So the file field is simply a string pointing to the right place.